# Is there a way to programmatically get the Android Q System color accent

Tags: android

As you noticed, Google has included a way to select a system wide color accent in the Android settings:

[image]

I first thought this would be impossible to use in my app, but Gboard succeed to use it to theme UI elements accordingly, as we can see in this news: https://9to5google.com/2019/05/08/android-q-gboard-accent-color/

I was then wondering if this is a public API, or of there is a way to get it from one way or another.

Thanks for any idea.

[image]

Comment: Well this seems new. Does it change in your app as well in default? Cuz it's like forcing coloraccent from the android side..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme as source which independent from `AppCompat` world.

I tested the follow snippet and it works fine when I changed the accent color on Android Q:

```
@ColorInt
fun getDeviceAccentColor(context: Context) : Int {
    val value = TypedValue()
    val ctx = ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault)
    ctx.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorAccent, value, true)
    return value.data
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to customize layout using this color? Do everything programatically isn't the nicest solution i think.

Comment: I'm not sure. You can if you set `android:theme` attribute to `Theme.DeviceDefault` on your Application, Activity or layout. I think you would like to use in your own theme as individual and Android is not supported to merge styles like in CSS.

Comment: I don't understand it correctly. Theme.DeviceDefault isn't available anywhere.